# Is this MySql query sql-injection protected?

Tags: php, injection

I have small php code, before discovering mysqli real_escape_string i was using a function with some regex rules to clean every user input by symbols, but for an email or a password, this is not a good solution. So i found this function to prevent a SQL injection.

```
$email = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['uemail']));

$query = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT user_id, uemail, user_password FROM users WHERE uemail='$email'");
```

Is this code protected from malicious inputs?

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is not a magic bullet for stopping SQL injection attacks.  There are ways that an attacker can pull-off an SQL injection attack, even if you are passing all inputs through `mysql_real_escape_string`.  See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string for an interesting thread on this subject.

It's highly recommended to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection attacks, instead of using `mysql_real_escape_string`.